# How to run jupyterhub using sudo. Error: commad not found

Tags: python, ubuntu, sudo, jupyterhub

I want to run `Jupyterhub` on my server.  I installed `Jupyterhub` from [the instruction](http://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html).  I try it from both my computer and the server where both running on Ubuntu 16.04.  When I start Jupyterhub without sudo, everything is Ok on my computer, and I can log in with my user and It starts the jupyter server. But when I run  jupyterhub from the server after login I get error 500: Internal server error and it seems its because of permission error

`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`

Then I tried to run jupyterhub using sudo: `sudo jupyterhub -f jc.py`  where `jc.py` is my configuration file. And I see this error:

```
sudo: jupyterhub: command not found
```

At first step, I don't know why sudo doesn't recognize jupyterhub command,
As the guide says, I install jupyterhub using conda.

To solve that problem I run jupyterhub from the path:

`sudo anaconda3/bin/jupyterhub -f jc.py` 
and this time I get this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'configurable-http-proxy'
```

And absolutely I'm sure that I installed  `'configurable-http-proxy'` when I run `conda install -c conda-forge jupyterhub  # installs jupyterhub and proxy`.

Why `sudo` doesn't recognize `jupyterhub`?
How can I solve that `PermissionError`?

Answer (score 1):

Please specify the path at which configurable-http-proxy is installed by conda.
Find path from shell using command
`sudo which configurable-http-proxy`

Make sure that this path is added to PATH variable of root user.
Check using
`sudo echo $PATH`

If not please add it to PATH and try again.

Comment: I think you are in a right way, but when I want to add Conda to $PATH, i get `sudo: export: command not found`. How can I do that?

Comment: Try adding ``c.ConfigurableHTTPProxy.command = '/anaconda3/bin/configurable-http-proxy' ``in jupyterhub_config.py (jc.py in your case) file. Assuming that path of configurable-http-proxy is ``/anaconda3/bin/configurable-http-proxy``

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Create a service, and give it root permissions on [service] tag.

Maybe my github here will help you:

[Github/Jupyter](https://github.com/Nouvellie/ubuntu/blob/ubuntu/contents/jupyter.md)

[jupyterhub.service] --> /etc/systemd/system/jupyterhub.service (User=root)

```
[Unit]
Description=Jupyterhub Service

[Service]
Environment="PATH=/opt/anaconda3/envs/<jupyterbase>/bin:/opt/anaconda3/bin:/opt/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
ExecStart=/opt/anaconda3/envs/<jupyterbase>/bin/jupyterhub
WorkingDirectory=/opt/<user>-jupyterhub
Restart=on-failure
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then:

```
$ sudo systemctl start jupyterhub.service
```

Answer (score -1):

pass the parameter `--allow-root`

Hope that helps

Comment: I think that is helpful when I'm using `jupyter notebook`, but I'm using jupyterhub.